# How to log final SQL queries with hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, log4j

Is it possible to log not HQL queries but final queries when using hibernate. I mean, the one that is sent to the database. I've tried different log level but I haven't seen it. And in my opinion it would be useful to debug some issues.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. That's what the [`hibernate.show_sql` property](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-optional-properties) does. You may also have finer control using the [logging configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-logging):

```
org.hibernate.SQL           Log all SQL DML statements as they are executed
org.hibernate.type          Log all JDBC parameters
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl  Log all SQL DDL statements as they are executed
```