# Hibernate read only entities says saves memory by deleting database snapshots

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

While going through the hibernate document and reading through the read-only entities, the following [hibernate official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/readonly.html) says,

Hibernate does some optimizing for read-only entities:

- It saves execution time by not dirty-checking simple properties or single-ended associations.
- **It saves memory by deleting database snapshots.**

I don't understand what does it mean by `deleting database snapshots`.

Is it referring to some optimization that happens in the database? If so, how does hibernate inform/hint the DB to do that optimization? Is this optimization a database specific feature and so not guaranteed across the databases?

Or is it referring to an optimization that happens with in the hibernate library? I doubt this is the case, because whether it is readOnly or not the query fired by hibernate to fetch the records is same, but want to make sure I am not missing anything here.

**UPDATE: As per the answer from @tgdavies, it helps hibernate not to keep the snapshots as the dirty checking is not needed. 
Subsequently would like to understand if there is any link between JDBC readOnly and hibernate readOnly to enable db optimization. As per the [Connection.html#setReadOnly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setReadOnly(boolean)) it says - `Puts this connection in read-only mode as a hint to the driver to enable database optimizations.`. And what are those hints?**

Can someone throw some light on how this optimization is actually achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Hibernate loads an object into a Session it creates a state snapshot of the current database state of the object, so that it can perform dirty checking against the snapshot.

As a read only object will never be modified, this snapshot is not needed and memory can be saved.

This is not an optimisation related to database access, but to reducing the memory used by the Session.

I doubt that Hibernate sets the JDBC connection to read only -- Hibernate doesn't know what else will happen in the Session. You could log the SQL Hibernate is sending to make sure: [How to log final SQL queries with hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689432/how-to-log-final-sql-queries-with-hibernate)

I'm not sure what optimisations the database can perform on a read only connection -- probably taking fewer locks in some isolation modes, but that's just hand-waving on my part.

Comment: I think that makes sense and helps hibernate to not maintain snapshots. I would like to understand if there is any link between JDBC readOnly and hibernate readOnly to enable db optimization. As per the [Connection.html#setReadOnly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setReadOnly(boolean)) it says `Puts this connection in read-only mode as a hint to the driver to enable database optimizations.`. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for throwing light on the hibernate maintained snapshot and its usage in the context of readOnly.